# Update table from other table where row equal with a value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to create a trigger to get values from one to table and transfer them to another table and update.

Something like this:

```
UPDATE  [dbo].[TABLE1]
SET     CapelaWin  = 2,
        ProcyonWin = 1
WHERE   [dbo].[table2].[VictoryNation] = 1;
```

I have already searched around thru stackoverflow and google but didn't find my answer.

Comment: What is the relation here between the two tables and when is your trigger supposed to fire. The Update statement above wouldn't execute. Do you have some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how the tables are connected(they should have relations with each Other) you can use this template to do your work

```
UPDATE  [dbo].[TABLE1]
SET     CapelaWin  = 2,
        ProcyonWin = 1
from [dbo].[TABLE1] inner join [dbo].[TABLE2] on [dbo].[TABLE1].fld1 =[dbo].[TABLE1].fld2
WHERE   [dbo].[table2].[VictoryNation] = 1;
```

and you should define when your trigger will fire.